# Writing to a text file which already been added as a resource file in Java

Tags: java, printwriter

I don't usually work with Java and got a problem with file management in Java. I'm using NetBeans IDE for coding Java.

I've added 2 **resource text files** under the same package of the main class of my Java program. I'm using one file to take input and want to write the output to the other file runtime. Reading data from 1st file is perfectly working using `ImputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader`. But, writing to the resource file is not working.

I've used following code:

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("outputFileName.text").getPath());
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
pw.write("Some String Data...");
```

And getting error at runtime as follows-

```
Jan 30, 2017 5:05:46 AM MyPackage.MyFile MyFunction
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file name with correct path.........
.........
.........
```

It's indicating that, in the 2nd line of this code segment is wrong. And I've printed the absolute path of the FILE object and it shows the correct one. Even I've checked that, both of the resource files are move under build folder.
But, another strange thing is `canRead()`, `canWrite()` and `exists()` functions- all are returning `false`!!!

I've searched a lot within this short time but got no solutions yet that meets my target. If my question is a duplicate one my apologies for that. But, what's wrong with this code? How can I solve this problem and be able to do what I want?

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java

Comment: A resource which is "embedded" within your application context long acts as a file, as, in most cases, it's not.  You can't write to them. If you need to write to the files, you have number of choices based on your needs, have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974857/where-should-i-place-my-files-in-order-to-be-able-to-access-them-when-i-run-the/27974989#27974989) for some more details

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer for this. So, I can't simply write to a file inside the jar. Can you please find me a way so that, I can read & write to text files in the same directory of the jar the? And how can I copy the resource files automatically to the jar's location?