# Singleton Serializable Database save method throws IOException

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

The goal of this class is to be able to load when the program starts and save when data is changed. I have used these same methods before, the save and load ones. For some reason I can not get it to work now? Any ideas?

```
package BackEnd;


import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Hashtable;


public class DataBase implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Hashtable<String, Account> accountTable = new Hashtable<String, Account>();
    
    private static int nextAccountid = 1;
    
    private static DataBase instance = new DataBase();
    
    AccountInstance account = AccountInstance.getInstance(); 
    
    private DataBase() {
        
    }
    
    public static DataBase getInstance() {
        
        return instance;
    }
    
    public static DataBase load() {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("./src/Data/data.dat"))))) {
            instance = (DataBase) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("load");
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            getInstance();
            System.out.println("error load");
        }
        return instance;
    }
    
    public static void save() {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("./src/Data/data.dat"))))) {
            oos.writeObject(instance);
            System.out.println("Save");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Save");
        }
    }
}
```

The save and load method are not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. This isn't really how you should be creating a singleton on Java; 2. You should not be referencing `src` in your code, it won't exist once the app is packaged and exported; 3. I'm worried that you trying to save the `Database` class itself and not the data ... what's going to happen to the `instance` field?  What is it pointing to when you re-load the class?; 4. Serialisation was never meant for the long term storage of data, it was meant as a means for over the wire transmission of object data

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Java Singleton Design Pattern Best Practices with Examples](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples)

Comment: Oh, and you should be printing your exceptions at the very least, if not logging them. I would also argue that the `save` and `load` methods should be throwing those exceptions, as it's the callers responsibility to decide how it should be responding to those

Comment: @MadProgrammer 1) I looked over the link you sent thank you! I will read into it and correct it.  2) What would be an alternative to saving on a local disk of a machine without using src? This is the only way I have learned in school so far. 3) I should be saving the HashTable instead of the whole class is what you are saying? Appreciate your help :)

Comment: 2. [Where should i place my files in order to be able to access them when i run the jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974857/where-should-i-place-my-files-in-order-to-be-able-to-access-them-when-i-run-the/27974989#27974989); 3. Yes, but I would consider using an alternative storage mechanism which better supports long term storage of data

Comment: @MadProgrammer Great! Thank you for the link, that really helps! Yeah I understand I should use an actually database such as mongo or sql, I am creating a personal project at the moment, I do not have much experience using databases like that. I will learn one day and implement it then! I really appreciate it you helped a lot!