# Relative path in Java for program that run on other machines

Tags: java, file, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm working on a Java program, and I need a relative path from the class KMeansMiner to the "file" folder. So far, I've been using an absolute path, and it worked fine, but now I need to run the program on other machines. I've seen some solutions here, but they don't seem to work. I've also tried a few solutions myself, but nothing seems to be working. I was advised against using "/", "../", etc., because they are specific to Windows. Can anyone provide me with a solution or an idea?

This is the structure of my project:
[image: This is the structure of my project]

I need a relative path to navigate back to the 'file' folder that has nothing to do with the JAR files.

Comment: Are you using the data in the "file" folder in a read-only fashion? Or are you also altering the data and then writing it to disk? This can be very important.  And I am assuming that you are distributing your application as a jar file, correct? If not, then you probably should be doing this. And if the data is read-only, then the appropriate way to access it is not as a file but rather as a class resource.

Comment: is best practice that every file/folder/number/string/whatever that could change is passed as parameter, via command line or configuration file !

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The files in the "files" folder should be set to both read and write. I will distribute the application as a JAR file. Do you have any ideas on how to find the relative path?

Comment: Also to be blunt, "*I've seen some solutions here, but they don't seem to work. I've also tried a few solutions myself, but nothing seems to be working.*", is a *terrible* problem statement as it tells us nothing of use. What specifically have you tried and what problems are you having with it?

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi It has been requested to do it through code! A relative path would be sufficient. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tried some ChatGPT solutions, but it didn't give me the complete path. Other solutions told me to transform the absolute path into a relative one, but I can't input any absolute path!

Comment: This is a common issue which affects all software developers.  Various platforms have conventions for storing application data in "well known locations" which avoid issues such as permission restrictions and otherwise cluttering the users file system.  For example, on Windows you might use `{user.home}\AppData\Remote\{name of your application}` - this means that no matter where you application installed, the location of the data your application uses is maintained in a consistent location.

Comment: You could make use of an installer to install the initial files to this location or extract them at runtime from the application build on first run, depending on your overall needs

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974191/get-current-path-of-executed-file/53982349#53982349)

Comment: `file`  folder is internal to your jar or is in the file-system ?

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi The folder "file" is part of the project (as you can see in the picture) and therefore, it will be included in the JAR. But now, I want a way to reference the "file" folder through code in IntelliJ.

Comment: *@StefanoRiffaldi The folder "file" is part of the project (as you can see in the picture) and therefore, it will be included in the JAR* It's therefore a resource path and not really a file. You can read from it but not write to it

Comment: If it is internal to the jar file, then it should not be written to. If it needs to be written to, it needs to be first extracted from the jar, or distributed outside of the jar.

Comment: @g00se It is a directory containing files. These files can be read, written, and added.

Comment: I'm confused. You said clearly that *The folder "file" is part of the project (as you can see in the picture) and therefore, **it will be included in the JAR*** If it's IN the jar then it can't be written to

Comment: @g00se no man, you are not confued, Vincenzo does