# Text file unable to be found and read

Tags: java, eclipse, file

Right now, I'm simply attempting to read the contents of a file stored in the same directory as my Java classes, and access the length. However, whenever the correct file name is passed to create a new `File` object, its length comes back as being zero. I assume that this is because the file cannot be found for some reason.

My file structure is as follows:

```
-src
--hw1 (package)
---TextSwap.java
---letters.txt
```

I try to create a file object with
`File file = new File(filename);`, where `filename` is equal to `letters.txt`.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287478/get-file-from-project-folder-java/36445369.

Comment: Maybe src/hw1/letters.txt might work.

Comment: @AliasCartellano That's it, thank you!

Comment: Make sure the [current directory](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java) is what you think it is

Answer (score 0):

```java
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("letters.txt");
```

Or try

```java
FileReader fr=null;
try
{
    fr = new FileReader("letters.txt");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException fe)
{
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).